# Password masking only works for JDBC Connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect

We have set our Kafka Connect to be able to read credentials from a file, instead of giving them directly  in connector config. This is how a login part of connector config looks like:

> "connection.user": "${file:/kafka/pass.properties:username}",
>
> "connection.password":
> "${file:/kafka/pass.properties:password}",

We also added these 2 lines to "connect-distributed.properties" file:

> config.providers=file
>
> config.providers.file.class=org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider

Mind that it works perfectly for JDBC connectors, so there is no problem with the pass.properties file. But for other connectors, such as couchbase, rabbitmq, s3 etc. it causes problems. All these connectors work fine when we give credentials directly but when we try to make Connect to read them from a file it gives some errors. What could be the reason? I don't see any JDBC specific configuration here.

EDIT:

An error about couchbase in connect.log:

```
[2021-12-02 11:50:19,580] ERROR [com.couchbase.io][SaslAuthenticationFailedEvent][20ms] Authentication Failure - Potential causes: invalid credentials or if LDAP is enabled ensure PLAIN SASL mechanism is exclusively used on the PasswordAuthenticator (insecure) or TLS is used (recommended) {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xbf785c7500000001","remote":"10.30.142.109:11210","status":"UNKNOWN","type":"KV","xerror":{"ref":"ae3ce600-7097-4077-9231-8ced290cd399"}} (com.couchbase.io:533)
[2021-12-02 11:50:19,580] WARN [com.couchbase.endpoint][EndpointConnectionFailedEvent][23ms] Connect attempt 9 failed because of AuthenticationFailureException: Authentication Failure - Potential causes: invalid credentials or if LDAP is enabled ensure PLAIN SASL mechanism is exclusively used on the PasswordAuthenticator (insecure) or TLS is used (recommended) {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xbf785c7500000001","remote":"10.30.142.109:11210","type":"KV"} (com.couchbase.endpoint:523)
com.couchbase.client.core.error.AuthenticationFailureException: Authentication Failure - Potential causes: invalid credentials or if LDAP is enabled ensure PLAIN SASL mechanism is exclusively used on the PasswordAuthenticator (insecure) or TLS is used (recommended) {"circuitBreaker":"DISABLED","coreId":"0xbf785c7500000001","remote":"10.30.142.109:11210","status":"UNKNOWN","type":"KV","xerror":{"ref":"ae3ce600-7097-4077-9231-8ced290cd399"}}
        at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.SaslAuthenticationHandler.failConnect(SaslAuthenticationHandler.java:488)
        at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.SaslAuthenticationHandler.maybeFailConnect(SaslAuthenticationHandler.java:293)
        at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.SaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead(SaslAuthenticationHandler.java:250)
        at com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.MemcacheProtocolVerificationHandler.channelRead(MemcacheProtocolVerificationHandler.java:84)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It says something about authentication but works fine when credentials are given directly. If the masking is not working correctly, how does it work for JDBC connectors?

Comment: Please provide some logs

Comment: Added some error logs @IskuskovAlexander

Comment: ConfigProvider interface is generic to all connectors. Your error seems specific to Couchbase, which I've not used. Is the S3 error similar?

Comment: Yes, errors are all about authentication. The problem is solved actually, gonna answer it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was quote marks in pass.properties file. The interesting thing is, even if credentials are typed with or without quote marks, JDBC connectors work well. Maybe the reason is it is the first line in the file but just a small possibility.

So, do NOT use quote marks in your password files, even if some of the connectors work this way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you share an example of a bad properties file vs. a good properties file?

Comment: the bad one:
usr="admin"
pass="admin"

the good one:
usr=admin
pass=admin   @dnault

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a bug in the JDBC connector -- what if the first and last character of your password were actually quotation marks? Seems like the JDBC connector would ignore them and use the wrong password :-D

Comment: @dnault yeah, the masking is working a bit unreliable for me right now. there was a problem with a password including % too.